# Where do I put registerDefaults?

Tags: iphone

I want to load and save settings. I don't know where I put registerDefaults. 
I put it in loadSetting. I think I did wrong. Do I have to put it at the end of application didFinishLaunch?

```
  - (void)loadSettings {    
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"key1",
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], @"key2",
                         nil];
        [defaults registerDefaults:dictionary];

        key1Value = [defaults boolForKey:@"key1"];
        key2Value = [defaults boolForKey:@"key2"];
    }

    -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  NSDictionary *)launchOptions  {    
        [self loadSettings];

    }
```

Comment: Why do you think you did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks ok to me. I think as long as you call it before any views are loaded, you should be fine.

Comment: Have you seen DrillDownSave example from Apple? I didn't see that example completely. But, registerDefaults is at the end of application didFinishLaunch. I don't understand that.

Comment: I haven't seen the example. I use NSUserDefaults quite a bit in my app, and I don't use -registerDefaults at all. I use [defaults synchronize] after I set the values, but that is it. I pull the value out NSDictionary *dict = [defaults valueForKey:@"settingsData"];